# How Do Namespaces Work When Using SPL_AUTOLOAD_REGISTER?

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I am learning how to use namespaces and autoloading in `PHP` today, and I appear to have hit a roadblock. Things seem to work when I don't use `spl_autoload_register` but instead `require_once`.

My folder structure is bare minimal:

```
- index.php
- class/
  - Users.php
```

In my `index.php` file I have:

```
<?php
require_once('class/Users.php');

echo User::get(1);
```

In my `class/Users.php` file I have:

```
<?php

Class User {
    function get($id) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

and this works absolutely fine, returning the ID of `1`

Ideally I will want to use an Autoload function and I discovered `spl_autoload_*` and this is what I tried to do, but with no success:

In my `class/Users.php` file I have:

```
<?php
namespace Users; // Added a namespace

Class User {
    function get($id) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

In my `index.php` file I have:

```
<?php
// Changed to using spl_autoload_register using an anonymous function to load the class 
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    include('class/' . $class . '.php');
});

echo Users\User::get(1); // Added the Users namespace
```

but I get an error:

```
`Class 'Users\User' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 7`
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [how Doctrine does it](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php), it's class loader works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add \ infront of the namespace path.

**Example**

```
\Users\User::get(1);
```

If you have to use a base path, like Traversable() you would also need to do

```
new \Traversable()
```

Answer (score 1):

The autoloader is called with the full class name as an argument, including the namespace. In your example this is `Users\User`, so you end up doing

```
include('class/Users\User.php');
```

This fails because the class definition is not in a directory named `Users` (by the way, `include` would emit a warning that it cannot find the file which includes the expanded filename, and this warning would make things clearer -- do you have disabled error reporting?)

It's a probably a good idea to have the autoloader fail on the spot when the file is not found so that the failure mode is more apparent. For example you could change it to

```
require('class/' . $class . '.php'); // require will end the script if file not found
```

or to something like

```
$result = @include('class/' . $class . '.php'); // see documentation for include
if ($result === false) {
    die("Could not include: 'class/$class.php'");
}
```